# How to use Spring Repository Keywords "CONTAINING" and "IN" in single repository statement?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I want to find persons that have similar name according to a provided list of name and age like in the following spring repository statement.

```
Page<Person> findByNameContainingInAndAge(Pageable pageRequest, Collection<String> listOfNames, Integer age);
```

I tried it but not working. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data may not support all possible queries. Sometimes you have to create a custom one. Try something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.name IN (:listOfNames) and p.age = :age ")
public List<Person> findByNameContainingInAndAge(@Param("listOfNames") Collection<String> listOfNames, @Param("age") Integer age);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But please consider containing keyword and pagination in the native query.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many combinations of "IN" and "Containing" on same field, but not worked. Finally, I concluded that theoretically, the repository statement mentioned in the question is not possible. 
Because the "CONTAINING" keyword accepts only one value for the field and the "IN" keyword accepts a collection of values for the field "name". So, applying both keywords on single field at same time in a single repository statement is not possible.